# auto hidden layout in vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

i want to make a layout that be visible on mouse over and hide automatically on mouse out. i try this code but it not give me any result;

```
public class DemoLayout extends VerticalLayout implements MouseOverHandler,
        MouseOutHandler,MouseUpHandler {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7610044813670041530L;

    public DemoLayout() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Mouse over");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Mouse out");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Mouse up");
    }
}
```

vaadin doesn't support layout mouse listener?
how can i implement this feature?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I don't know of such listeners for layouts up to Vaadin 7.4.3. The good news is that you have at least a few options:

1. the handlers you're implementing are from `com.google.gwt.event.dom.client` package which is bundled in the vaadin-client jar. You're, probably unintentionally, mixing client-side & server-side classes which is most likely not what you're after. However you can try to create your own widget and implement those handlers on the client side as suggested [here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/91706) and/or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879349/adding-a-mouseoverhandler-to-an-element)
2. you may be able use the CSS [:hover pseudo-class](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) to some degree as discussed [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/264902)
3. **(perhaps the simplest)** you could achieve a similar effect with a click. Take a look at the [SliderPanel](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/sliderpanel) add-on to avoid re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Depending on your exact use case, you could probably just use CSS and the :hover pseudo class.
2. If :hover doesn't work then you could use the excellent [Mouse Event Extension](https://vaadin.com/addon/mouse-events-extension) addon.

Comment: Thanks. Even if it's fairly new,it's good to know someone implemented such an extension (+1)